# Checking if userInput is number with exception

Tags: java

Im trying to check whether the input from the User is an int or not.

Heres my code so far:

```
static int readInt(Scanner userInput) {
    int intValue = 0;

    try {
    System.out.print("Please enter a number:");
    intValue = Integer.parseInt(userInput.nextLine());


    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    Input.readInt(userInput);

    }
    return intValue;
}
```

The problem is: if I first give it input which is not a number and then after that i give it a number it always returns 0. If i give it a number the first attempt it returns the number I have given it.

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

edit: Im only allowed to use Integer.parseInt and Exceptions.

Comment: You are not assigning the return value of `Input.readInt(userInput);` to your `intValue`

Comment: Consider wrapping the input code in `while`-loop to ensure that the program only continues forward when valid input has been received.

Comment: If you're only allowed to use Integer.parseInt and Exceptions, please edit your question and add this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid your problem, in the catch block you need to assign this `Input.readInt(userInput)` to your variable. like this :

```
intValue  = Input.readInt(userInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not setting the variable in the catch

```
intValue = Input.readInt(userInput);
```

Comment: That solved it, thanks! so I dont have to put "Input.readInt(userInput);" in my catch then at all, right?

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is overhead here. use loop:

```
Integer result = null;
do {
    System.out.print("Please enter a number:");
    try {
        result = Integer.parseInt(userInput.nextLine());
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.print("Not a number");
    }
} while(result==null);
return result;
```